# Using the exchange lemma provides weird result

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cross-product

I know that if we have a square $n \times n$ matrix $A$ in F and two vectors $v,u$  in $\mathbb F^n$, following the exchange lemma we can show that:

$$\langle Au,v\rangle = \langle u, \ A^*v\rangle $$

Suppose that I have the following dot product:

$$\langle \ A^*Av,v\rangle $$

I can show using the exchange lemma that :

$$\langle \ A^*Av,v\rangle = \langle v, \ A^*Av\rangle $$

On the other hand, I can show using the exchange lemma that:

$$\langle \ A^*Av,v\rangle = \langle Av, Av\rangle $$

Therefore I get:

$$\langle v, \ A^*Av\rangle = \langle Av, Av\rangle $$

How is it possible that $\langle v, \ A^*Av\rangle = \langle Av, Av\rangle $?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a contradiction somewhere?

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB , What is the problem?

Comment: No. I'm trying to understand how is it possible that $$\langle v, \ A^*Av\rangle = \langle Av, Av\rangle $$

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB You proved it... (`\times` gives you $\times$).

Comment: Thanks. Fixed my question. This equality just seems so weird.... I though I was doing something wrong.

Comment: If the A were real and symmetric matrix I would understand why it is correct. Otherwise It just seems like there are cases where this equality doesn't stand.

Comment: @Git Gud But if I take : $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
 Then the equality won't hold

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB To give a counter-example you should provide an inner product and $v$ to which the equality fails. You should also show your computations so people can pinpoint your mistakes.

Comment: Git Gud suppose I take $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

And,
$$ v =\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Then

$$ \ A^* = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then we get :

$$ \langle v, \ A^*Av\rangle = \sqrt(2) $$

And,

$$ \langle Av, Av\rangle = \sqrt(2)$$

And I found out that I had computation error..  You were right. Thank you.